# fopen problem with php simple test

Tags: php, file, simpletest

I'm seriously stumped by this one. I'm learning to use simpletest to run my unit tests. In one of my sample test classes, I'm testing a parser which takes a file and works on the content.

I decided to make a file with sample content to test the parser. This file was to be in a subdirectory. After running`fopen()`  and `fwrite()`, I kept getting errors that the file does not exist. I tried a `file_exists()` and it also return false. I then removed the path and left only the filename, this time it worked but I couldn't find the file. I moved the code out of the test class and run it and it worked fine and the file was in the current working directory.

It seems to me that, running the code in the test methods creates the file somewhere else other than the current directory. That is the problem, I can't find the files. I have done a deep search, manually gone through my wamp folders and still cannot find it.

I'd appreciate it if someone can help me out here.
I'm running php 5.3.5 on wampserver 2.0i. Simpletest is version 1.1 Alpha 3. Thanks.

Comment: Just specify an absolute path to fopen?

Comment: That works. Thanks. Still wondering where the files are though. @John

Comment: Maybe a permission problem...

Comment: Using the getcwd and printing that result should tell you where the script put those files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call getcwd http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php to get the current working directory.

Comment: Okay, that actually worked. The cwd inside a method is B:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11 . I wonder why. Thanks. Didn't occur to me to simply check the cwd since I didn't expect it to change. But why inside apache? :?

Comment: The script is executed by the apache service/daemon and so the working directory is commonly the location of the executable.

Comment: Is it just the simpletest scripts? Why doesn't that happen with my other scripts as well? Any resources on this? Thanks.

Comment: If you really want to control the cwd you can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php.  But I dunno using absolute paths gets you to the same place with less mess IMHO e.g. $root = '/my/work/dir/'; $aPath = $root . 'tmpFolder1';  instead of chdir you control it via the $root variable.

Comment: Thanks. I already used a workaround. I used chdir() since the test environment will change and changing the variable will not make the tests automated then. 
Until now I never had this issue. Guess I need to read about working directories and how they change, if I can find resources.